# Apache Tiles integration with JSP and Servlet webapp

Tags: java, jsp, maven, apache-tiles

I have successfully integrated Apache Tiles with my webstore which is built on pure JSP and Servlet technology (Tomcat 8). I am using Apache Tiles only and only for page templating, nothing else and my maven pom includes the dependency as follows:

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I have the feeling that `tiles-extras` pulls in everything that I may not even be using. My question is which specific jar should I include for templating? I am using a `template.jsp` which acts as the base JSP template page which looks as follows:

**template.jsp**

```
  <body>
        <table class="noborder">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header"/>
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/><br/><br/>
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

**WEB-INF/tiles.xml**

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="homePage" template="/jsp/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/jsp/header/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/jsp/content/home/home.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/jsp/footer/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>
```

**web.xml**

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Tiles Dispatch Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.tiles.web.util.TilesDispatchServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Tiles Dispatch Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.tiles</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you not use the tiles-extra tags add only tiles-jsp